# Azure python create empty vhd blob

Tags: python, azure

I am using Azure python API to create page blob create_blob and updating the header using the link provided http://blog.stevenedouard.com/create-a-blank-azure-vm-disk-vhd-without-attaching-it/ and updating my actual image data using update_page but when i am trying to boot the VHD i am getting provision error in Azure. "Could not provision the virtual machine" can any one please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be something wrong with your vhd image. I would suggest you have a look at [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/narahari/2013/01/14/windows-azure-virtual-machines-gotchas/).

Here is a snippet of that article:

Please make sure of the following when uploading a VHD for use with Azure VMs:

- A VM must be generalized to use as an image from which you will create other VMs. For Windows, you generalize with the sysprep tool. For Linux you generalize with the Windows Azure Linux Agent (waagent). Provisioning will fail if you upload a VHD as an image that has not been generalized.
- A VM must not be generalized to use as a disk to only use as a single VM (and not base other VMs from it). Provisioning will fail if you upload a VHD as a disk that has generalized.
- When using third-party storage tools for the upload make sure to upload the VHD a page blob (provisioning will fail if the VHD was uploaded as a block blob). Add-AzureVHD and Csupload will handle this for you. It is only with third-party tools that you could inadvertantly upload as a block blob instead of a page blob.
- Upload only fixed VHDs (not dynamic, and not VHDX). Windows Azure Virtual Machines do not support dynamic disks or the VHDX format.
  **Note:** Using CSUPLOAD or Add-AzureVHD to upload VHDs automatically converts the dynamic VHDs to fixed VHDs.
- Maximum size of VHD can be up to 127 GB. While data disks can be up to 1 TB, OS disks must be 127 GB or less.
- The VM must be configured for DHCP and not assigned a static IP address. Windows Azure Virtual Machines do not support static IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are two points that you could focus on.

1.The VHD file should be a .vhd file. So ,your code should be 'blob_name='a-new-vhd.vhd''

2.The storage account  and the VM which you created should be in the same location.

Hope it helps. Any concerns, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks, the blob that i am creating ends with .vhd only and i am trying to use vhd in the same location VM but still the problem persists